# How to access a pointer made within an if statement, outside of it?

Tags: c++, pointers, conditional-statements

I am making a simple program to play a certain battle call depending on a user picked pokemon. I have one main class (Pokemon class), and two classes which inherit a virtual battleRoar() function from the main class.
This is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Pokemon{
public:
    virtual void battleCall(){
    }
    virtual ~Pokemon() {}
};

class Weedle: public Pokemon{
public:
    Weedle(){
        cout << "Weedle Weedle!" << endl;
    }
    void battleCall(){
        cout << "-v- weedle" << endl;
    }
};

class Pikachu: public Pokemon{
public:
    Pikachu(){
        cout << "Pikaaaachu!" << endl;
    }
    void battleCall(){
        cout << "pikachu!!" << endl;
    }

};


int main(){

    cout << "Please pick a pokemon." << endl;
    cout << "1. Weedle" << endl;
    cout << "2. Pikachu" << endl;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 1){
        cout << "You picked a weedle!" << endl;
        Weedle chosenPoke;
        Pokemon *p1 = &chosenPoke;

    }
    else if (a == 2){
        cout << "You picked a pikachu!" << endl;
        Pikachu chosenPoke;
        Pokemon *p1 = &chosenPoke;
    } else { cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;}
    cout << "Would you like to hear your pokemon's battle call?" << endl;
    cout << "Yes or No" << endl;
    string choose;
    cin >> choose;
    p1->battleCall();       //produces error: use of undeclared identifier 'p1




    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is the main class pointers which point to the subclass are no longer accessible outside of the conditional. In this case, I know it would be simple to call on the roar in each branch of the conditional. However, I would like to be able to call on whichever subclass was made with a pointer, rather than creating calling the function for each and every variation of the conditional.

Comment: You can declare `Pokemon *p1;` before the if() however `p1 = &chosenPoke;` is not going to work since you are taking the address of a temporary `chosenPoke;` which no longer exists outside of the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the pointer before the `if` block and change the creation of the object you want to return.

```
Pokemon *p1;
if (a == 1){
        cout << "You picked a weedle!" << endl;
        /* Weedle chosenPoke;  -- don't construct the object on the stack */
        p1 = new Weedle();
}
...
p1->battleCall();
delete p1;
...
```

This solves the immediate problem of the undeclared identifier but adds the burden that you must delete the object when it is no longer required - or change your code to use smart pointers.

Comment: When deleting the object, I would say "delete p1;", right?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) this solves my problem

Comment: I've added the delete to my example

Comment: @Tony I think `p1` should be set to nullptr. As mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @jalajan - Take note of the issue highlighted by Kunal Puri's answer. When you have an invalid choice the program will crash unless you test for a valid pointer; which can be as simple as putting the call and delete in an `if (p1) { ... }` block.

Answer (score 3):

Though major problem is already answered, You might face issue while applying the answer. Pointer `p1` is not set to any valid value which might give segmentation fault.

You have to do something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Pokemon> p1;

if (a == 1) {
    cout << "You picked a weedle!" << endl;
    p1 = std::make_unique<Weedle>();
} else if (a == 2){
    cout << "You picked a pikachu!" << endl;
    p1 = std::make_unique<Pikachu>();;
} else { cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;}

cout << "Would you like to hear your pokemon's battle call?" << endl;
cout << "Yes or No" << endl;
string choose;
cin >> choose;

// In case of invalid input, it'll work!!!
if (p1 != nullptr) {
    p1->battleCall();
}
```

Comment: Thank you much for the assistance :-) I decided to encase it within an if conditional

Comment: @jalajan If you are using raw pointer, don't forget to initalize it with `nullptr`

Answer (score 1):

You may find that even though `main()` is not yet a complicated function, breaking it down into smaller function allows you to more logically scope variables.

e.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<Pokemon> 
create(int choice)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Pokemon> result;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "You picked a weedle!" << std::endl;
        result = std::make_unique<Weedle>();
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "You picked a pikachu!" << std::endl;
        result = std::make_unique<Pikachu>();
    } 
    else 
    { 
        std::cout << "Invalid choice" << std::endl;
    }

    return result;
}
```

full working example:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e20a47e0d5e1de5